# Aftereffects - How to do curly smoke like this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, photoshop-effects, adobe-after-effects

Alright, I've looked through tutorials and come across https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25LhGggJKfo as the closest match, however its not quite the toon CURLY smoke I need. I'm trying to make this, animated:

[image]

How can I make toon smoke with all the curliness?